# nginx-gunicorn Flask app not pointing to my application directory on CentoOS 7

Tags: python, nginx, flask, centos7, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy a little flask app on a Centos7 server, I followed the passages in [this guide](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvii-deployment-on-linux) that was basically to set up `nginx` with `/etc/nginx/conf.d/microblog.conf` :

```
server {
    # listen on port 80 (http)
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        # redirect any requests to the same URL but on https
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
    # listen on port 443 (https)
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name _;

    # location of the self-signed SSL certificate
    ssl_certificate /home/cocchi/git_dir/covid20/certs/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/cocchi/git_dir/covid20/certs/key.pem;

    # write access and error logs to /var/log
    access_log /var/log/covid20_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/covid20_error.log;

    location / {
        # forward application requests to the gunicorn server
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /static {
        # handle static files directly, without forwarding to the application
        alias /home/cocchi/git_dir/covid20/app/static;
        expires 30d;
    }
}
```

then setting up the `gunicorn` istance in `/etc/systemd/system/covid20.service` ([this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)):

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=cocchi
WorkingDirectory=/home/cocchi/git_dir/covid20
Environment="PATH=/home/cocchi/git_dir/covid20/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/cocchi/git_dir/covid20/venv/bin/gunicorn -b localhost:8000 -w 4 microblog:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and now when I access the HTTPS website I can see that `flask` is somehow working cause it redirects automatically to `auth/login` but I got `nginx error` that looking at `/var/log/nginx/error.log` :

```
2020/04/24 19:19:46 [error] 8391#0: *6 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/auth/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.40.1.217, server: _, request: "GET /auth/login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.50.3"
```

is apparently related to the fact that `nginx` is not pointing to my project directory `home/cocchi/git_dir/covid20` but still to the default `/usr/share/nginx/html` and I do not get why.

I also changer ownership to the directory both to nginx and then to my user with no success:

```sh
ls -ls /home/cocchi/git_dir/
0 drwxrwxr-x 10 cocchi nginx 335 Apr 24 17:23 covid20
```

I wondered around several guides and websites but found nothing, does anybody got a clue?? Sure it's pretty simple and I'm loosing something here...

Thank you so much in advance for any help!

Comment: covid20? Isn't covid19 bad enough? 